# Error while creating custom Alert Dialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am getting the following error while creating a custom `Alert Dialog` in `Android` application.

**Error**

```
requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Following is my code for the custom `Alert Dialog` creation.

**Code**

```
AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(home.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Title here..");
alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alertdialog);
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: can you post the whole snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code snippet here for custom Dialog:

use new Dialog instead of DialogBuilder

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        d.setTitle("This is custom dialog box");
        d.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove .create() from first line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as guide:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    YourActivity.this);

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your title here...");

alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Your message here...")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // Your works
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alertdialog);
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try this :*

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(home.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Title here..");
alertDialogBuilder.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alertdialog);
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```